# JQuery. Recursively Parse XML. How?

Tags: jquery, xml

How can I parse the following XML and get values by index? The example below works but it returns all values at once. How do I gain access to each individual node value while inside the Each loop? Is there a way to do it by index?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!---->
<GetAccount>
  <id>free2rhyme</id>
  <password>letmein</password>
  <name>jerry mcguire</name>
  <age>29</age>
  <sex>m</sex>
  <location>salt lake city, utah</location>
  <language>english</language>
  <signup>00/00/0000</signup>
  <confirmed>y</confirmed>
  <status>a</status>
</GetAccount>


$.get('getAccount.xml', null, function (data) {

    var getAccount = $(data).find('GetAccount').each( function(){

    var value = $(this).text();
    alert(value);

    });
}, 'xml');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will itearte trough all element 'GetAccount' subelements and their values:

```
$.get('getAccount.xml', null, function (data) {
    var getAccountID = $(data).find('GetAccount').each( function(){
      $('*', this).each(function(i,e){
        alert('index='+i+' name='+e.tagName+' value='+$(e).text())
      });
    });
}, 'xml');
```

Comment: This is a great start. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery treats XML almost exactly as it does HTML. (The `.html()` method is absent when dealing with XML documents.) So, to get the contents of the `<id>` child of a `<GetAccount>` node, do this:

```
var getAccount = $(data).find('GetAccount').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).find('id').text();
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: var value = $(this).find('id').text(); Can 'id' be replaced with some sort of index number? Basically there is no need for a Each loop if I am accessing the values directly as I could just do var value = $(this).find('GetAccount id').text();

Comment: @Vini That should work fine, as long as you're sure there's only one `GetAccount` and `id`. Otherwise it will combine the text contents of every node the selector matches.

Comment: @Vini jQuery supports pseudo-selectors, including [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), if that helps... not quite a replacement for XQuery, but...

Comment: @mblase75: and if I need it recursively, what would be the best method?

Comment: @Vini If you need a loop, use what was in my answer. If it's actually recursive -- meaning you have `<GetAccount>` nodes inside of your `<GetAccount>` nodes -- then there's something wrong with the XML constructor.